# Drag and Drop in Eclipse - java project

Tags: eclipse, drag-and-drop

I am unable to drag and drop files from my finder (on mac OSX) to any eclipse project folder. More surprisingly, when I add files from directly in my finder into the eclipse workspace, I don't find it added in the eclipse workspace's view. Anybody has an idea ?

Comment: did you try a refresh of the workspace?

Comment: @acostache yes I did but it didn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed Eclipse on Mac sometimes takes really long to refresh files which made me think that darg&drop did not work. Restarting Eclipse did not help, restarting the Mac helped. In any case, FileSync plugin seems to solve this issue for me.

There is still a problem though. Drag and drop from finder to Eclipse always makes a copy in Eclipse. Moreover, when dropped the file modified timestamp changes marking CVS file dirty. I have to perform cvs update after dropping. Annoying and confusing.